# How to use nuget packages in deployment for a visual studio solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I have a solution which contains multiple c# projects. Some of these projects have nuget dlls as references.
By default nuget pulls all the dlls to a folder called *packages* in the solution folder (The dlls may depend on other nuget dlls so nuget pulls them too to the packages folder). This works fine for a normal build.

Now I want to deploy my application where all the .dlls are present in a single folder. What is the best way to collect all the nuget dlls into that folder.

**Note**: While adding Nuget references to a project, `CopyLocal` is set to `true` by default, so the nuget dlls are copied into the bin folder of that project. So, I can pull those dlls form there. But I am not sure how to pull the second order dependencies (Other nuget dlls on which the nuget dlls I reference depend on) as they are not copied to the bin folder of project.

Comment: A build command should move everything necessary (including all secondary dependencies) into the bin folder for you.  Is that not working for some reason?  Also, if you are preparing for a deployment have you tried using the publish command in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I am not sure how to pull the second order dependencies(Other nuget dlls on which the nuget dlls I reference depend on) as they are not copied to the bin folder of projec

According to the document [Dependency resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/dependency-resolution):

> Any time a package is installed or reinstalled, which includes being
>   installed as part of a restore process, NuGet also installs any
>   additional packages on which that first package depends.
>
> Those immediate dependencies might then also have dependencies on
>   their own, which can continue to an arbitrary depth.

So, when we install one nuget package to our project, NuGet will add the nuget package dll and its dependencies to the project. Besides, NuGet will set the property of `CopyLocal` to `True` by default for the dependencies. In this case, all the dependencies will also be copied to the `bin` folder.

For example, when we install the nuget package `Microsoft.Owin` to the Asp.net application project, its dependency `owin` will also be installed to the project by default and the property of `CopyLocal` is also set to `True` by default. After installation complete, the dependency `owin` will copied to the `bin` folder.

So, to resolve this issue, please make sure the dependencies of the installed nuget package are also added to the project, and check if the property of `CopyLocal` is set to `True`.